# What happens if there were some connection in the pool and database server switches

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, oracle11g, connection-pooling

I have a small query about what will happen to the application pool active connection if the database server switches.
I am using asp.net 4.o hosted on IIS 7.5 and oracle server running on linux.
Using ado.net to connect oracle server.

Comment: what do you meant by server Switching

Comment: two server with same virtual ip. One goes down another goes up.